# Replace column by 0 based on probability

Tags: python, numpy

How to replace column in the numpy array be certain number based on probability, if it is (1,X,X) shape.
I found code to replace rows, but cannot figure out how to modify it, so it is applicable for columns replacement.

```
grid_example = np.random.rand(1,5,5)
probs = np.random.random((1,5))
grid_example[probs < 0.25] = 0
grid_example
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

grid_example = rng.random((1, 5, 5))
probs = rng.random((1, 5))

grid_example[..., (probs < 0.25).flatten()] = 0
print(grid_example)
```

**Output**

```
[[[0.         0.43887844 0.         0.         0.09417735]
  [0.         0.7611397  0.         0.         0.45038594]
  [0.         0.92676499 0.         0.         0.4434142 ]
  [0.         0.55458479 0.         0.         0.6316644 ]
  [0.         0.35452597 0.         0.         0.7783835 ]]]
```

The notation `[..., (probs < 0.25).flatten()]` applies the boolean indexing to the last index. More on the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).